# Full screen & window mode Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have this code :

```
if(false) 
    {

        this.setUndecorated(true);

        this.setExtendedState(this.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }
    else 
    {

        this.setSize(1024, 768);

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        this.setResizable(false);
    }
```

My app runs in a window mode but when i change the false statement to true, it runs in Full screen mode.

I don't get what represent the false statement in If?

Thank you for your time

Comment: It will never go in `if` block. Why you are doing in this way? What you want to achieve?

Comment: Don't set the size because it will not work on another resolution or system.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't get what represent the false statement in If?

There is no meaning of this type of condition because it creates a **Dead code** it means it will never be reached at all.

Don't use set size to full screen the window because it will not work on different resolution and system.

**how it will look on resolution below [1024 X 768]?**

`this.setExtendedState(this.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);` is a good approach to full screen it.